# Flexible string handling in Visual Studio 2008 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, unicode, tchar

I'm slowly starting to get the hang of the _T stuff in Visual Studio 2008 c++, but a few things still elude me.  I can see the benefit of the flexibility, but if I can't get the basics soon, I think I'll go back to the standard way of doing this - much less confusing.

The idea with the code below is that it scans the parameters for -d and then stores the text that follows that in the string variable fileDir.  It also ignores any other parameters.

Any help is appreciated.

```
//Console application
Parameters::Parameters(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{ 
    _Tstring fileDir;  // Is there some kind of _t variable to use here for a string?

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i = i + 1)
    {           
        if (_tccmp(argv[i], _T("-d")) == 0)  // this appeared to accept anything starting with -
        {           
            i = i + 1;
            fileDir = argv[i]
        }
    }   

    _tprintf("Parameter value found: %s\n", fileDir);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_tstring` to represent and `std::string` with a `TCHAR` parameter. Also, the name of the function is `_tcscmp`, not `_tccmp` so I don't see how that code snippet could even compile?

To be honest, I wouldn't bother with any of that, though. The whole `TCHAR` stuff was useful back when people were writing code that was to be portable between Windows 9X (which was Ansi internally) and Windows NT (which was/is Unicode internally). These days, there's very little benefit to using the macros.

If you want to do anything, you can switch to `wchar_t` entirely. That means prefixing string literals with "L", as in `L"Some wide-char string"` and using the 'w' versions of functions (e.g. `std::wstring`, `wcscmp`, etc). But even that might be considered overkill for many scenarios.

Comment: I would argue about TCHAR, people may want to wrote cross-platform apps.

Comment: TCHAR is not portable to any other platform anyway (you'd have to re-write all the macros yourself on the other platform). If you want to be cross-platform, I would stick with UTF-8 encoding internally. Or use some cross-platform library (like Qt, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a string value and you're using MFC or ATL, your _Tstring can be CString.

If you want to copy a pointer value, your _Tstring can be LPTCSTR.  (This works whether or not you're using MFC or ATL.)

As codeka said, your _tccmp needs to be _tcscmp.  An alternative, if you're using MFC or ATL, is CString's Compare method.

You didn't show how the caller delivers parameter argv to your constructor.  If argv came from your _tmain function, make sure the parameters to _tmain are correct.